# Titanium: SQL Lite "Attempted to access unknown result column time"

Tags: sqlite, titanium

I'm getting this error when trying to execute a SQL Lite query:

> "Attempted to access unknown result column time"

The SQL in question is:

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('spacev3');
var tRS = db.execute('SELECT time(vreme) FROM locdb ORDER BY ID DESC');
while (tRS.isValidRow())
{
  var ttime = tRS.fieldByName('time');
  Ti.API.info('ttime=' + ttime);
  tRS.next();
}
tRS.close();
```

According to SQL lite specs, that should work?

The DB Schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locdb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lat TEXT, lon TEXT, alt TEXT, speed TEXT, vreme TEXT);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
var tRS = db.execute('SELECT time(vreme) as time FROM locdb ORDER BY ID DESC');
```